# Truffle migrate exception on windows

Tags: truffle-migration

I was trying to migrate a contract in windows, I am getting the following pop-up message.

[image]

I already installed truffle node module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [known issue with Truffle with Windows](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/150). Or use PowerShell instead.

If that even not works, give a try with `truffle.cmd migrate`

Comment: PowerShell worked for me